# Google Earth Engine Timelapse Error: Image collection must have at least one image to create video

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am learning to make timelapse video in google earth engine. But i am getting an error as i run the task.
Here is the report
Task details: jakarta

State: Failed

Started: 7m ago (2020-01-10 10:00:45 +0700)

Runtime: 19s

Id: P63GZE2VVQ5KZ7K2AEF4G3BR

Error: Image collection must have at least one image to create video

```py
var image = ee.Image(landsat.filterDate('2014-01-01','2019-12-31').filterBounds(point).sort('CLOUD_COVER').first());
var years = ee.List.sequence(2014,2019,1)
print(years)
//Print the image to the console

print('A Landsat scene',image);

//Define vis parameter

var trueColor = {

  bands: ['B4','B3','B2'],

  min: 6000,

  max: 13000,

};

//Add the image to the map

Map.addLayer(image,trueColor,'True Color Image');
// Combine all data in single collection
var peta = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate('2018-01-01','2020-01-01');
var timelapse = peta.map(function(img){
return image.visualize(trueColor);
});
print(timelapse)
var coll4Video = timelapse.map(function(img){
    return image.multiply(512).uint8();
});
Export.video.toDrive({
    collection: coll4Video,
    description: "jakarta",
    scale: 30,
    framesPerSecond: 2,
    region: geometry
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/847652634730f535132b40f7edcbdd29

Answer (score 1):

Look at the output of your `print(timelapse.size())`. It says that the image collection has zero elements, which is why you are getting the error.

This is because you have filtered to images after 2018, but the [deprecated collection `LANDSAT/LC8_L1T`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/landsat#landsat-collection-structure) contains only images in April 2017 and earlier. Please read the linked page and descriptions of non-deprecated Landsat collections to determine what you should use instead; I cannot advise you on Landsat-specific matters.

---

While I was determining this, I noticed another error in your script:

```
var timelapse = peta.map(function(img){
  return image.visualize(trueColor);
});
```

In this `.map()` operation, the variable for the image in `peta` that is declared in the `function` is `img`, but on the next line you are using the unrelated variable `image` (which is declared earlier outside the `.map()`). Thus, if your collection wasn't empty, you would have ended up exporting copies of the same image, not a time series.

This is reported as a warning in the editor, indicated by a red underline and a hover message “Mapped functions should use their parameter.” The deprecation of `LANDSAT/LC8_L1T` is also shown as such a warning. I recommend you check these warnings when writing your script, so that you can find more problems on your own before asking for help.